# Jquery- Add a property to a <div> next to a known class

Tags: jquery

I need to add a property `active` to the closest next div with class name `onebyone-carosel`. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
    {% for deals in best_deals %}
        <div class="item"> <!-- I want add property `active` over here.-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/auction/{{deals.id}}">
                    <img src="media/{{deals.images.0.image}}" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <font size="2">
                        <div class="best_deals_info">Title : {{deals.title}}</div>
                        <div class="best_deals_info">Start Date : {{deals.start_date}}</div>
                        <div class="best_deals_info">End Date : {{deals.end_date}}</div>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

How do  I do this?

Comment: Do you have any jQuery code that you've tried already?

Comment: `$(".onebyone-carosel .item").attr('active', '');`

Comment: @JqueryKing - WOuldnt this add `active` to all the items? PS: I've a loop and hence will have multiple divs with class item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
$(".onebyone-carosel .item:first").attr('active','');
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ag7je2so/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".onebyone-carosel").closest('.item').attr('active', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

`$(".onebyone-carosel").children("div").first().attr('active','');`

**Explanation:**

`.children("div")` will get all `<div>`s found in parent element.

`.first()` will return the first `<div>` from the list of children divs.

and finally `.attr('active','')` will add your `active` attribute with an empty string as value.